# Creating a static reference versus a singleton

Tags: java, mongodb, singleton

I am using the java driver for mongodb, and the documentation says to:

> "you should create a single Mongo instance, and you can use it in every request."

Using a single instance sounds like a singleton.

In other places for a different library I have read the instructions saying that I should create a static reference as it is thread-safe.

Can someone explain the differences between a singleton and creating a static reference?

So the actual code that I need to instantiate either statically or via a singleton would be:

```
Mongo m = new Mongo( "localhost" , 27017 );
```

Can someone explain both methods and the underlying differences if any?

Answer (score 4):

In Java you typically use a static variable to implement the Singleton pattern.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/singletons/

Answer (score 4):

You have 3 issues: singleton, static reference and thread-safety.

You have a singleton if you can only create one instance of a class.  That's useful since things would get messed up if you had two instances of Mongo running.  However, you cannot implement the singleton design pattern for Mongo in your code: you can call `new Mongo()` anywhere you want and create as many instances as you want.  You just have to be careful you don't do so, but it shouldn't be very hard.

To implement a singleton, the class designer will very often use a static reference as follows:

```
public class MyClass {
  private static final MyClass SINGLETON = new MyClass();

  private MyClass() {...}   // !!private, not accessible

  public MyClass getSingleton() { return SINGLETON; }
}
```

And you will only ever have one single instance of `MyClass` since the constructor is private and the only way to get an instance is through `MyClass.getSingleton()`.  Obviously the Mongo designer would have had to design the `Mongo` class as such; there is nothing you can do to make it a singleton.

As far as thread-safety is concerned, I don't quite see the link with singleton.  A singleton class must be made thread-safe: if many threads change and read the state of a singleton, you need proper synchronization to make sure all threads see the same values.  I don't know Mongo, but I would bet it is a thread-safe class.

Comment: Mongo is thread-safe, and is a has a connection pool, I just need to create a single instance of it, so a static instance is the way to go then?

Comment: @codecompleting Yes, somewhere in your main class that deals with Mongo you should have `private static final Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);` and make sure you don't create another Mongo.  If you have a good object design, other classes will never access `mongo` directly; if you do need other classes to access `mongo`, you could make a `getMongo()` method in your main class.

Answer (score 3):

Singleton is a *design pattern* where you have one instance of an object shared amongst the rest of your code.  Static variables are a Java *language feature*.

In order to implement a Singleton, you would usually use static variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Singleton pattern on an object if you only want to be passing around a single instance of this object to other objects and methods that need to use this single instance. Use a static reference if you only want to be using the object's class statically (i.e as a static reference).

Answer (score 0):

If only one class is using your singleton object there is no visible difference in number of objects created.

Assuming you need an object of classASing using Singleton approach

```
ClassASing {
     private static ClassASing obj = new ClassASing();
     private ClassAsing(){...}
     public static ClassASing getNewObject(){
          return obj;
     }
}
```

Using Singleton approach

```
ClassB{
    private ClassASing singObj = ClassASing.getNewObject();
}
```

- no matter how many instances of ClassB created all of them will be using the same object of ClassASing

using static reference

```
ClassB{
    private static ClassA sObj = new ClassA();
}
```

* no matter how many instances of ClassB created all of them will be using the same reference pointing to the same object.

Not much difference here 1 object being used in both the cases.

Now if u consider another sencario that you need object in two of your classes.

singleton approach

```
ClassB1{
            private ClassASing singObj1 = ClassASing.getNewObject();
        }

ClassB2{
            private ClassASing singObj2 = ClassASing.getNewObject();
        }
```

- no matter how many instances of ClassB1 created all of them will be using the same object of ClassASing
- no matter how many instances of ClassB2 created all of them will be using the same object of ClassASing that ClassB1 is already using so only one object of ClassASing

Static reference approach

```
ClassB1{
    private static ClassA sObj1 = new ClassA();
}

ClassB2{
    private static ClassA sObj2 = new ClassA();
}
```

- no matter how many instances of ClassB1 created all of them will be using the same reference sobj1 pointing to the same object
- no matter how many instances of ClassB2 created all of them will be using the same reference sobj2 pointing to the same object but this object is different from the one created in ClassB1 so now you have two objects of ClassA.